# How to get Apache commons math SummaryStatistics to use a better minimum?

Tags: statistics, apache-commons-math

`org.apache.commons.math4.stat.descriptive.SummaryStatistics`

SummaryStatistics appears to use a naive implementation of min(). It uses the default constructor of the internal container which defaults to a zero value. If your data set is greater than zero the statistics will never represent the true minimum.

I'm hoping there is a way to initialize it with a known value to avoid this, but I am not seeing that. Is there a way around this without using my own implementation for statistics?

thanks

Comment: You might search the issue tracker for the commons math project to see if it is a known problem, and you might consider asking there if there isn't already an answer. If you can see where the problem originates, you might consider submitting a patch. I know this isn't really a satisfying answer, but as both a consumer and a developer of open source math tools, I know the situation is problematic in some respects.

Answer (score 0):

`SummaryStatitics` uses the `Min` univariate statistic object to compute minimums.

Based on the implementation for the 3.6.1 release, [`Min` is initialized to `Double.NaN`](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Min.java;h=c87e6f199516f0782c44e742f27d3ed0352c3c6e;hb=refs/heads/3.6.1-release#l58).

When adding new values to `SummaryStatistics`, `Min` checks if a new value is less than the current minimum as well as checks if the current minimum is `Double.NaN`.  [If either of those conditions is true, the new value becomes the minimum](https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Min.java;h=c87e6f199516f0782c44e742f27d3ed0352c3c6e;hb=refs/heads/3.6.1-release#l77).

In short, `SummaryStatistics` correctly computes the minimum even when all added values are positive.

As example:

```
SummaryStatistics summary = new SummaryStatistics();

System.out.println("Initial Minimum (should be NaN):     " + summary.getMin());
summary.addValue(10.0);
System.out.println("First Value Minimum (should be 10):  " + summary.getMin());
summary.addValue(5.0);
System.out.println("Smaller Value Minimum (should be 5): " + summary.getMin());
summary.addValue(20.0);
System.out.println("Larger Value Minimum (should be 5):  " + summary.getMin());
```

generates the following output:

```
Initial Minimum (should be NaN):     NaN
First Value Minimum (should be 10):  10.0
Smaller Value Minimum (should be 5): 5.0
Larger Value Minimum (should be 5):  5.0
```